# How to copy a Azure function from one deployment slot to another?

Tags: azure, function, azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

I have an Azure Function App with a single function.

I created a Deployment Slot.

I'd like to copy the function to this Deployment Slot.

( In other words I'd like to duplicate the Function App. )

Is this possible ?

Note that Swap is not the same because the Deployment Slot initially starts out with no functions.

Answer (score -1):

We gave up slots - swapping/moving/"deploying" between them is actually a deploy so you just get a worse deploy experience overall, poor API and not enough control.

I *believe* to get what you're after you need to deploy the function again, specifying the other slot and then you have what you want.

We've found a better solution is:

- ignore slots, they're constant pain, failure and instability
- create 2x resource groups my-function-prod, my-function-dev and put a Function App in each of those
- use Github Actions + Github releases to deploy to either the dev or prod Function

Comment: But now you need distinct vnet, subnet, pe, pe-nic, etc.  Is that correct ?